# How to make alist with two list?

Tags: list, emacs

Example:

```
(setq foo '("f" "o" "o"))
(setq bar '("b" "a" "r"))

(setq foobar `(,foo .  ,(list bar))) 
;; Give me a normal list ( ("f" "o" "o")  ("b" "a" "r") ) which is not what I want.
```

I want to get `( ("f" "o" "o") . ("b" "a" "r") )`. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cons` to get a dotted pair:

```
(setq foo '("f" "o" "o"))
(setq bar '("b" "a" "r"))

(cons foo (list bar))
-> (("f" "o" "o") ("b" "a" "r"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

```
(setq foobar `(,foo ,bar))
(memq foo foobar)
-> (("f" "o" "o") ("b" "a" "r"))
```